# Strip HTML tags from string, keep specific

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I'm trying to strip all html tags from string and keep only specific (keep the tag and the attributes),
I have this:

```
set objRegExp = new RegExp
with objRegExp
.Pattern = "<^((b)|(i)|(em)|(strong)|(br)|(img))>.*</.*>"
.Global = True
end with
```

and using:

```
objRegExp.replace(request.form("content"), "")
```

doesn't change anything.

I need this for a forum that I build, which supports WYSIWYG editor and I want to prevent xss & sql injections.

Comment: No VB6 here.  Question is overtagged.

Answer (score 2):

To strip all HTML Tags:

```
Public Function RegexAllHtml(strValue)
   Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
   With RegularExpressionObject
    .Pattern = "<(.|\n)+?>"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
   End With
   Dim strResult: strResult = RegularExpressionObject.Replace(strValue, " ")
   Set RegularExpressionObject = Nothing

   RegexAllHtml = strResult
End Function
```

To remove specific tags (eg. SPAN) you could use something like:
`<SPAN[^><]*>|<.SPAN[^><]*>`

Or to keep specific tags (eg. b an bold): `<(?!/?(?:strong|b)\b)[^>]*>`

BTW: Most WYSIWG editors let you configure which tags are not safe and those then are removed before saving the content! See for example CKEditor: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent

Answer (score 0):

Function RegexAllHtml... is...

If the string contains the string "<spec...>" it will be removed. I don't think it's a valid function.
Should we warn users not to use "<" and ">" individually?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: As you are referencing a method from John's answer I assume you want to add to it. To add more information to answers please use Comments (like this one) or write a new, improved answer altogether. You will gain access to commenting on posts at 50 Reputation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).